# radiusd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Tags: mariadb, freeradius, centos8, radius

I am very new to linux and freeradius and want to learn about this for my work, however I encounter some challenges.

I have installed freeradius on Centos 8. I installed it and it worked just fine but after installing mariaDB, issues came out when trying to start the service.

```
[root@FPM-FreeRad01 ~]# systemctl start radiusd.service
Job for radiusd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status radiusd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.



[root@FPM-FreeRad01 ~]# systemctl status radiusd.service
â radiusd.service - FreeRADIUS high performance RADIUS server.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/radiusd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-06-23 09:13:53 PST; 9s ago
  Process: 2900 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/radiusd -d /etc/raddb (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2897 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/radiusd -C (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2891 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /etc/raddb/certs/bootstrap (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2889 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R radiusd.radiusd /var/run/radiusd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1789 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 23 09:13:53 FPM-FreeRad01.int.ahinet.ph systemd[1]: Starting FreeRADIUS high performance RADIUS server....
Jun 23 09:13:53 FPM-FreeRad01.int.ahinet.ph systemd[1]: radiusd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 23 09:13:53 FPM-FreeRad01.int.ahinet.ph systemd[1]: radiusd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 23 09:13:53 FPM-FreeRad01.int.ahinet.ph systemd[1]: Failed to start FreeRADIUS high performance RADIUS server..
```

I've been dealing with this since yesterday and I tried searching for other related problems but cannot find some answers so I try asking for help here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you